# Commutative Diagram for group structure

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

I remember seeing once a commutative diagram that explained group structure. Where the associativity, identity element, inverse, multiplication and all was shown in a singular diagram, it is trivial to device diagrams for each thing seperately but I like the neatness of having it all condenced into a singular diagram.

I might be remembering wrong but I am fairly certain it exists. So my question is how would one do a commutative diagram that portray the axioms of groups? I have started with the simple ones and I just get stuck as I try to tie them together.

Comment: Maybe look at Algebra: Chapter 0 by Aluffi. Around chapter 10 section II there is an explanation of a _group object_ in a category, complete with diagrams that reflect the group axioms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find what you want, I think, in §4.1 of Awodey's *Category Theory*.

You can download a version of the chapter [from Awodey's own website here](http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/80-413-713/notes/chap04.pdf), so I won't attempt to reproduce the relevant diagrams here!

Comment: While not quite what I wanted it suffices for me to construct it myself, thank you!

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: @Shaun Awodey has recently taken those old-version chapters down from his website.